# Polynomial algebra of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Then what does this mean  $\mathbb{K}[V]$, polynomial algebra on $V$? I didnt understand the terminology. Please help me.

Comment: The [symmetric algebra on $V$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra), I assume. In practice, the algebra of polynomials in the indeterminates given by a basis of $V$.

Comment: Is it symmetric algebra on V or symmetric algebra on $V^*$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a basis of $V$. A polynomial P(X) in $\Bbb K [V]$ means a polynomial in the coordinates of $X$ in this basis.

Remark : the fact that $P(X)$ is a polynomial in $\Bbb K [V]$ does not depend on the choice of the basis, because for a given vector, by a change of basis, the new coordinates can be written as a linear combination of the coordinates in the initial basis.